# Как вывести список доступных часов от настоящего времени в php?

Tags: php, время, datetime

Например сейчас 15.00 настоящее время, при нажатии на select будет выводится доступное время 16.00, 17.00, 18.00 и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <? $now = getdate(); ?>
    <? for($hour = $now['hours'] + 1; $hour < 24; ++$hour): ?>
        <option value="<?= $hour ?>"><?= $hour ?>:00</option>
    <? endfor; ?>
</select>
```